# Does C support anonymous members of unions?

Tags: c

I have a union that is an overlay of an array on three floats:

```
union {
    float currents[3];
    struct {
        float run;
        float standby;
        float sleep;
    };
} MyCurrents;
```

`run` can be accessed either by `MyCurrents.run` or `MyCurrents.currents[0]`.

Is there a way to have the `currents` array anonymous, such that I can access `run` by simply using `MyCurrents[0]`? Having the `.` accessor seems a bit redundant in this use case.

I realise I can use `((float*)&MyCurrents)[0]` but that's horrible and I'm not sure it's actually a reliable method to use.

Comment: No, as it would be ambiguous if you have 2 arrays in the `union`. Also note that `run`, `standby` and `sleep` are all aliased by the same `currents[0]`, which might not be what you want.

Comment: No. You are talking about something like "indexer" in C# or similar.

Comment: Yep, absolutely right, I've wrapped them a  `struct`. My mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the C standard, members that are structures or unions may be anonymous. This works because the members within them are not anonymous, so every subobject within the enclosing structure or union has a name. Anonymous members of other types are not supported (except that bit fields used for padding may be anonymous, but they are also not normally accessible).

(The C grammar allows you to include declarations without names (C 2018 6.7.2.1 1: The *struct-declarator-list* is optional in a *struct-declaration*), but they do not create members, and there would be no way of referring to them. And declaring a member without a name requires omitting the entire *declarator* of the grammar, which includes (per 6.7. 1) `*` for pointers, `[` and `]` for arrays, and `(` and `)` for functions. So the grammar would permit you to declare `struct { float; float f; } foo;` but not `struct { float [3]; float f; } foo;`.)

Comment: Out of interest, what exactly does the first `float` in `struct { float; float f; }` do, if it doesn't create a member? Does it just happen to be legal but does nothing at all?

Comment: It is reserving memory space, which can be accessed by other means.

Comment: @jfowkes: It does nothing. It is an artifact of the grammar. They want to allow a *specifier-qualifier-list* there because that includes the *type-specifier* you need in order to declare an anonymous structure or union there. But a *type-specifier* can be other types too, like `float` or `int`. So the grammar permits `struct { struct { int x; } /* no name here */; … }` to allow anonymous structure or union members, but it also permits `struct { float /* no name here */; … }` as an undesired side effect. In the latter case, no member is declared, and no space is reserved.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: No, it is not. The size of `struct { int; float x; } foo;` in a Clang version I just tried is four bytes, the size of the `float`. The `int;` has no effect.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That is surprising... I would think that if wrapping it in union with named `int` will give the access to this `int`...

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yep. this code is behaving as you say: https://ideone.com/Y9E3Hk . So it's a pretty useless and even misleading artifact.